# Refresh after successful Ajax submission not working

Tags: jquery

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $("#login").click(function(){
    $.post($('#loginform').attr("action"), $('#loginform').serializeArray(), function(data) {
                if(data == 'Success'){
                    $(document).ajaxStop(function() { location.reload(true); });
                }else {
                    $('#loginmsg').html(data);
                }
        });
    });
});
```

Everything is working perfectly fine except the page is not refreshing after a successful submission. How can it be done?

Server-side:

```
<?php
if (empty($_POST) === false){
    $username = $_POST['username'];
    $password = $_POST['password'];

    if (empty($username) === true || empty($password) === true){
        $errors[] = 'You need to enter a username or password';
    }
    else if (user_exists($username)===false){
        $errors[] = 'We can\'t find that username in our database.';
    }
    else if (user_active($username) === false){
        $errors[] = 'Activate your account.';
    }   else    {
        $login = login($username,$password);
        if ($login === false){
            $errors[] = 'Incorrect combination.';
        } else {
            $_SESSION['user_id'] = $login;
            $errors[] = 'Success';
            exit();
        }
    }
}else {
    $errors[] = 'No data received!';
}
output_errors($errors);
?>
```

Comment: What's exactly the result of `console.log(data)` ?

Comment: Are u sure about your Ajax response? put alert inside if(data == 'Success'), then check.

Comment: You're doing the reload in an `ajaxStop` handler. It won't happen unless there are other AJAX requests outstanding, or you do another AJAX request.

Comment: @Edwin Alex, Whatever is script inside the if(data == 'Success'){//whatever script} - is not working! I tried putting 'alert(data);' didn't work. Probly cuz this is a log on form I'm creating.

Comment: @Yoosuf Then your response might be wrong. Put alert(data) before if condition and check what response you are receiving

Comment: @Edwin Alex, thanks so much for pointing out. If I put in anything wrong, the alert data says whatever I made it to echo in the PHP. But when I type in the right username and password, it says, nothing! What do I do?

Comment: I can't figure out your problem now. If it is different, make new post

Comment: YOu're calling `exit()`, so you never do `output_errors()` in the success case.

Answer (score 0):

You need to wite:

```
window.location.reload()
```

OR

```
window.location.href=window.location.href
```

Comment: If `location` hasn't been shadowed, `location` is the same as `window.location`

Comment: @dystroy what about the `true` argument that Arvind doesn't include?

Comment: @JanDvorak The argument simply tells the browser to force a new request. OP was right to include it.

Comment: @dystroy sorry for not replying you. The problem is with the  if(data == 'Success').

Answer (score 0):

You dont need to call [ajaxStop()](http://api.jquery.com/ajaxStop/). Change your success code to:

```
if(data == 'Success'){
  location.reload(true);
}
```

Comment: What does the `data1 that is returned from the server look like? Is the `else` code being executed?

Comment: yes, I think if(data == 'Success') <--- is the wrong part. I need to know how to fix that though.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the call to `exit()` in the PHP. It's preventing it from going to `output_errors($errors)` in the Success case, so you never send the `Success` message to the client.

Comment: thanks for pointing out. I took out the exit() and now the alert data says 'success' but however, the page is still not refreshing. And do I need the exit() code there?

Comment: Did you also remove `ajaxStop()` as rob said? You don't need `exit()` if the script ends after `output_errors()`.